# XLSX files in azure blob storage get downloaded as zip files

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

We have some files in our Azure blob storage - they are all **xlsx** files.
When we download them via Azure portal (we navigate to the storage account, then to the container, and then select a file and download it) it downloads and saves as zip file.

If after downloading we change its extension to xlsx then Excel will recognize it and open without issues. However, something is forcing that extension to change from xlsx (as we see it in the container) to the .zip whilst it is downloaded.

The same happens when we access the files programmatically (via c# code) or generate a shared access signature.

What could it be and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: No way to reproduce this issue, can you try downloading copying and pasting the full url in browser?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the problem. Does the file you upload have the `xlsx` extension?

Comment: xlsx files are actually a zipped directory of xml files, so they are actually zip files. Their "Magic Number" (aka "file signature") is the one of zip files (50 4B 03 04 [PK]). So "What could it be" -> something somewhere is checking for known magic numbers and safely doesn't trust the extension. "how to fix it" -> find what's this something, unfortunately, I have no clue about this.

Answer (score 0):

my work around when accessing xlsx files programmatically with C#, is to manually add the mime type specifically for the xlsx file type as, they were one's giving me issues(pdf and pictures work fine), PS, I store filenames in my DB with a corresponding filename. i.e

```
if (YourModel.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx"))
            {
                return File(YourModel.FileData, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            }
```